# Issue Search Bar with React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

got this code to perfom a product search trough and endpoint in a react/redux proyect, everything is working fine, we would like to show a "No products Found" message when there's no result for given term, instead im gettin the entire list of products

[image]

This is for search

```
export const searchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "search",
  initialState: {
    loading: 0,
    list: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    readySearch: (state) => {
      state.loading += 1;
    },
    searchData: (state, action) => {
      state.list = action.payload;
      state.loading -= 1;
    },
    closeSearch: (state) => {
      state.list = [];
    },
  },
});

export const { readySearch, searchData, closeSearch } = searchSlice.actions;

export const isloading = (state) => state.search.loading;
export const list = (state) => state.search.list;

export const search = (text) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(readySearch());
  const data = await axios
    .post("general/product_search_list/", {
      name: text,
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      if (response.data == 0) {
        const allData = await axios.get("general/product_search_list/");
        return allData.data;
      } else {
        return response.data
      }
    });

  dispatch(searchData(data));
};

export const close = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(closeSearch());
};
```

This is for render result

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={_handleClose}>
  {_isloading > 0 ? (
    <>Cargando</>
  ) : (
    <List component="nav">
      {_list.map((product, index) => (
        <ListItem
          button
          className={classes.textWrap}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => selectProduct(product)}
        >
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.text}
            primary={product.name}
          />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  )}
</ClickAwayListener>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show that no results were found, you could simply do the following:

```
<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={_handleClose}>
  {_isloading > 0 ? (
    <>Cargando</>
  ) : (
    <List component="nav">
      {_list.length ? _list.map((product, index) => (
        <ListItem
          button
          className={classes.textWrap}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => selectProduct(product)}
        >
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.text}
            primary={product.name}
          />
        </ListItem>
      )) : <>No products found</>}
    </List>
  )}
</ClickAwayListener>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for you're help, makes sense, already tried no result. think the awnser is here, but can't figure that out

`export const search = (text) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(readySearch());
  const data = await axios
    .post("general/product_search_list/", {
      name: text,
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      if (response.data == 0) {
        const allData = await axios.get("general/product_search_list/");
        return allData.data;
      } else {
        return response.data
      }
    });

  dispatch(searchData(data));
};`